# SSRS 2008 - SubReport page break is ignored

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have 1 master report which contains 3 subreports. 1) Subreport by LOB, which contains 4 line charts and a table; 2) Subreport by Site, which contains 4 line charts and 2 tables; 3) Subreport by Site Details, which contains 1 table.

Issue: When the master report executes, the Subreport #1 is recognizing the pagebreak, but Subreport #2 & #3 are getting combined in Subreport #2 even though I set the "Page breaka after" in the 2 tables in Subreport #2.  The tables are positioned at the bottom of the line charts. I have one more subreport to be created which totals to 4 subreports in master repor, but it is giving me issue in splitting the subreport #2 and #3.

Please advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new rectangle in your report, then drag and drop your subreport #2 into the rectangle. Right click on the rectangle and select Rectangle Properties. On the General tab, click the "Add a Page Break After" checkbox. This should put a page break between subreports #2 and #3.